# how to access the magnetometer of mpu9250?

Tags: c, embedded

i have accessed mpu-9250 using address 0x68 and reading the data of accelerometer and gyroscope.

but now when i changed address to 0x0C to access magnetometer and whenever tried to read data,but it will not give acknowledgment.

i have also enable_bypass_i2c_pin.

i have used below code: i have issue to get data of magnetometer.

```
readBytes_jt(0x68, MPU9250_RA_ACCEL_XOUT_H, 14, buffer);
    *ax = (((int16_t)buffer[0]) << 8) | buffer[1];
    *ay = (((int16_t)buffer[2]) << 8) | buffer[3];
    *az = (((int16_t)buffer[4]) << 8) | buffer[5];
    *gx = (((int16_t)buffer[8]) << 8) | buffer[9];
    *gy = (((int16_t)buffer[10]) << 8) | buffer[11];
    *gz = (((int16_t)buffer[12]) << 8) | buffer[13];

//read mag
    writeByte_jt(0x68, MPU9250_RA_INT_PIN_CFG, 0x02); //set i2c bypass enable pin to true to access magnetometer
//  delay(10);
    delay_s_jt(10);

    writeByte_jt(0x0C, 0x0A, 0x01); //enable the magnetometer
//  delay(10);
    delay_s_jt(10);

    readBytes_jt(0x0C,MPU9150_RA_MAG_XOUT_L, 6, buffer);
    *mx = (((int16_t)buffer[1]) << 8) | buffer[0];
    *my = (((int16_t)buffer[3]) << 8) | buffer[2];
    *mz = (((int16_t)buffer[5]) << 8) | buffer[4];
```

Comment: Why did you switch byte order on magnetometer data? I mean: MSB and LSB of accel are read out in inverse order.

Comment: `(int16_t)x << 8` invokes undefined behavior in case `x` has a value larger than 0x7F. Start by fixing that severe bug. How exactly does it make sense for you to use `int16_t` for raw binary data anyway?

Comment: #define MPU9150_RA_MAG_ADDRESS         0x0C
#define MPU9150_RA_MAG_XOUT_L  0x03
#define MPU9150_RA_MAG_XOUT_H  0x04
                                                                                          #define MPU9250_RA_ACCEL_XOUT_H     0x3B
#define MPU9250_RA_ACCEL_XOUT_L     0x3C
#define MPU9250_RA_ACCEL_YOUT_H     0x3D
#define MPU9250_RA_ACCEL_YOUT_L     0x3E

Comment: see the diffrence of defined register order of lsb and msb.because of that reason i have to read in reverse3 order.and actually i have stopped at line where i try to communicate with magnetometer means that when enable to magnetometer.

Comment: in the function of write_byte,when it send start condition,it does not get any acknowledgement.